# For a Normal Distribution: when not given an $f(x)$, just probabilities, how do you find $E(x^2)$ to get the standard deviation?

Tags: probability

I'm studying for a final in my Probability class tomorrow by going through the problems in the book and making sure I can do them. However, I hit a few roadblocks. In this question, I'm not sure how to find $E(X^2)$ (because I'm trying to find the standard deviation). I'm going in to the problem assuming that I need to find $E(X^2)$ in order to find the standard deviation. If I don't, how would I go about solving it? I already know what µ is (0.5, due to symmetry of the graph). If I know how to do part a), then I'm confident I can do part b) on my own.

An equation given is $E(X^2) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x^2f(x)dx$. However, the problem doesn't give an equation, just probabilities. So, how would I go about integrating this without $f(x)$?

> Suppose $X$ has normal $(μ,σ^2)$ distribution, and $P(X≤0)=1/3$, $P(X≤1)=2/3$.
>
> a) What are the values of $μ$ and $σ$?
>
> b) What if instead $P(X≤1)=3/4$?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please include what you've already worked out (or at least thought about) in your question; you'll find you'll get more helpful answers this way anyway.

Comment: The first is more pleasant. The right tail and the left tail each have probability $1/3$, so the mean is easy by symmetry.

Comment: I added context to the question.

Comment: This isn't really an integration question, but more like looking up in a standard normal / z-table, and figuring out how to use that for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable 
$$
Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}
$$
is a standard normal, the tail probabilities of which you can look up in a table. Let's consider one of your known values, and I'll transform it into the standard normal step by step:
$$
P(X\leq 0) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
$$
P(X-\mu\leq -\mu) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
$$
P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\leq -\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
$$
P\left(Z\leq -\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
You already decided $\mu=\frac{1}{2}$ for part (a), so we have
$$
P\left(Z\leq -\frac{1}{2\sigma}\right) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
Now we look in the appropriate [standard normal table](http://www.deeannef.com/apstats/normal/normtbl2.gif) and we see that a standard normal is less than a threshhold with probability $1/3$ when that threshhold is approximately $-0.44$, so we know that is our threshhold:
$$
-0.44 = -\frac{1}{2\sigma}
$$
Now solving gives
$$
\sigma = \frac{1}{0.88} \approx 1.136
$$
So we got that $P(X\leq 0)= \frac{1}{3}$ if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0.5,1.136^2)$; you can check this as a forward problem to make sure you did things right, or [use WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=probability%20NormalDistribution%280.5%2C1.136%29%20%3C%200) to check to make sure that a normal with that mean and variance is less than zero about one-third of the time. In this case because we rounded and use a z-table with two significant figures, we're close-ish but not not dead on.

A more exact evaluation in terms of the normal CDF written in terms of error functions gives
$$
\sqrt{2}\text{erf}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) =\frac{1}{2\sigma},
$$
or if you had a z-table out to 16 digits, you'd get this
$$
-0.4307272992954575 = -\frac{1}{2\sigma},
$$
which leads to a [probability much closer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=probability%20NormalDistribution%280.5%2C1.160827281711311%29%20%3C%200) to $1/3$ (in fact this answer is also good to 16 digits).

Comment: Thank you! I'd forgotten about using Z, which I now remember my professor doing something similar with in an example in class.